# ng2-material : change dialog content

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using ng2-material in order to build my angular2 application.
ng2-material just offer two types of basic dialogue components, but I need to change their content.

So I need to know how can I do that??
this is what am using

```
   let config = new MdDialogConfig()
        .textContent(``)
        .clickOutsideToClose(true)
        .title('')
        .ariaLabel('Lucky day')
        .ok('save')
        .cancel('cancel')
        .targetEvent(ev);

    this.dialog.open(MdDialogBasic, this.element, config)
        .then((ref: MdDialogRef) => {
            ref.whenClosed.then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    this.status = 'You decided to get rid of your debt.';
                }
                else {
                    this.status = 'You decided to keep your debt.';
                }
            })
        });
```

I am not able to identify a **template URL** in place of **textContent** like in Angular material :

```
$mdDialog.show({
  controller: DialogController,
  templateUrl: 'dialog1.tmpl.html',
  parent: angular.element(document.body),
  targetEvent: ev,
  clickOutsideToClose:true,
  fullscreen: useFullScreen
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the url for the template as the textContent like this:

```
 let config = new MdDialogConfig()
    .textContent('dialog1.tmpl.html')
    .clickOutsideToClose(true)
    .title('')
    .ariaLabel('Lucky day')
    .ok('save')
    .cancel('cancel')
    .targetEvent(ev);
```

It worked for me so hopefully it works for you.